# Opposite of get_weights() in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

The `get_weights()` function in Keras returns the weight matrix along with the biases of a layer in a neural network. Let's say a variable `x = layer.get_weights()`. I'll transfer the value of `x` to a different network. In the new network, I'd like to add a layer to a trained network, but with the weights and biases of this newly added layer being equivalent to `x`. In other words, I'd like to use the same layer of the old network in the new one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean opposite as in `set` instead of get?
You can assign weights in Keras using `set_weights` - see documentation here https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/